# how to change the directory location in command prompt using C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, process, directory

I have successfully opened command prompt window using C# through the following code.

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"d:\pdf2xml";
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;


    p.Start();

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"pdftoxml.win32.1.2.7 -annotation "+filename);

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd D:\python-source\ds-xmlStudio-1.0-py27");

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"main.py -i example-8.xml -o outp.xml");

    p.WaitForExit();
```

But, i have also passed command to change the directory.

problems:

1. how to change the directory location?
2. Cmd prompt will be shown always after opened...

Please guide me to get out of those issue...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use p.StandardInput.WriteLine to send commands to cmd window. For this just set the p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput to ture. like below

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        //p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c D:\\pdf2xml";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.Start();

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd D:\pdf2xml");
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("d:");
```

Comment: @ Waqar: Thanks Waqar.Cmd prompt windwod did not shown anything.i think it get hanged due to p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
this line...

Comment: @ Waqar : I have to use this command. main.py -i example-8.xml -o result.xml.But it won't shown anything.In normal cmd prompt it works fine.What is the problem here...

Comment: @Saravanan if you want to read the output of your command then you need to call following String output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Comment: @ Waqar :No, actually i couldn't invoke this command main.py -i example-8.xml -o result.xml through C#.This is a python code i want to run from C#.This program takes one input xml file and generate another xml file.

Comment: @Saravanan Actully iam not aware of python commnds. But what i can suggest you is that make sure the both main.pi and input xml file is placed to path where you moved your directory location from cmd

Comment: :yes both in the same directory.but it did not run the program

Comment: @Saravanan can you post part of your code from where you creates the Porcess object to the lines where you pass command. May be i can help you then.

Comment: @Saravanan i am not sure but try to write this `p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"main.py -i D:\python-source\ds-xmlStudio-1.0-py27\example-8.xml -o D:\python-source\ds-xmlStudio-1.0-py27\outp.xml");` because if main.py is in any bin directory (like other compilers are in there bin directory) then main.py will be asuming that xml will be in the directory where main.py is residing. If this is the problem then you can pass the full path of xml files.

Comment: Sorry waqar i tried ur code.it did not work as well...what we do?

Answer (score 16):

To change the startup directory, you can change it by setting p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory to the directory that you are interested in. The reason that your directory is not changing is because the argument `/c d:\test`. Instead try `/c cd d:\test`

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 ...
 p.Start();
```

You can hide the command prompt by setting p.StartInfo.WindowStyle to Hidden to avoid showing that window.

```
 p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx

Answer (score 3):

use `System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` instead

You may also Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/f07f7744-0ea5-40b3-a787-ea1c10ec55f3)

[and this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513578/net-cmd-proces-start-cant-change-directory)

```
processStartInfo .WorkingDirectory = @"c:\";
```