# How continuously communicate to Cmd?

Tags: c#, cmd

I found how to open cmd in C#.

But I can use Inputstream only once.

#### Create Cmd Process

```
ProcessStartInfo CmdInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process cmd = new Process();


CmdInfo.FileName = @"cmd";
CmdInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
CmdInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
CmdInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

CmdInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
CmdInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
CmdInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
cmd.StartInfo = CmdInfo;

cmd.Start();
```

Now we can use cmd.StandardInput and cmd.StandardOutput.

#### Use Cmd

```
// Use cmd 1
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd");
cmd.StandardInput.Close(); // if don't close, I can't get output

Console.WriteLine( cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ); // Done!

// Use cmd 2
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\"); // It will occure ObjectDisposedException
```

I want solve this problem.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513578/net-cmd-proces-start-cant-change-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to get far with that approach.  The code is a hint ProcessStart ! It's a new process! After you've started the process it's completely seperate to the one in which your code resides, the only way you would be able to communicate with this new process is via COM or remoting or some other inter application communication channel... MSMQ etc.

As far as I know the cmd (command prompt) offers none of these.

I think you'll want to study up on powershell...

[Calling PowerShell From C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251076/calling-powershell-from-c-sharp)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

etc etc

Answer (score 1):

The command shell executable will not process commands from a redirected standard input until the input is closed.

You have three choices:

1. Create a new process for each command.
2. Pipeline all of the commands that you want to execute, then close the standard input handle.
3. Create a batch file containing all of the commands and then execute that.

If you choose to create a new process for each command, use cmd.exe's "/C" command line switch to execute the command rather than passing it through standard input.